# Why does <?php get_search_form(); ?> results in a blank page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to implement a search functionality on my blog page (the website is built from scratch, not using a WordPress theme).

I added this line of code `<div class="search-blog"><?php get_search_form(); ?></div>` to my archive.php file. I also added a searchform.php file to my theme's directory using sample code I found online. Here it is:

```php
<?php /* Template Name: Blog */ ?>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Blog Posts', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
    </label>
<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( ' >', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
</form>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

However, when I enter a search term in the search box I get a blank page with only the footer showing. Why? I did some research and also added search.php to the theme's directory (some suggested search.php is needed to actually show the results of the search). But that made things even worse because then the blog page didn't load at all.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked if your form is not hidden in HTML and is visible inside source code?

Comment: Thank you. How would I check that? I moved  <div class="search-blog"><?php get_search_form(); ?></div> to the top of the page underneath the banner and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try again using the get_header() function instead of including the header?

well

```
<?php /* Template Name: Blog */ ?>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

here instead of line 2

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

can you use this?

Comment: Thank  you so much for you help. I made the change you had suggested. Now I get the entire footer section underneath the search box. Also, when I type in a search term in the search box, I am still getting a blank page with only the footer showing. Do you know what might be going wrong here?

Comment: I am here to help you.
Sorry, forgot to mention.
You should do this for the footer with the same method.
Just like here:
<?php get_footer(); ?>

If it doesn't work, report back, please!

Answer (score 0):

With one last overlooked change;

```
<?php /* Template Name: Blog */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<label> <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span> 
<input type="text" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Blog Posts', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" /</label>
<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( ' >', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
</form>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Search term text box type is must be "text"

Comment: Thank  you very much for your help.  I updated searchform.php with the modified code you provided above (with <?php get_footer(); ?> and input type="text") and nothing changed. Still seeing a footer under the search box and getting blank page+footer when entering search term.

Comment: I understand that you are working on a demo project to improve yourself.
You have made adjustments on the search form and search result page templates.
If you're trying to understand the problem here, share all the codes. If you just want to fix the problem, download a sample blank theme from underscores.me and transfer the codes in search.php, searchform.php to your theme.

Comment: I am trying to understand the problem and fix the problem. I am trying all the suggestions on this thread and reporting the results in hopes of getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

add a file in your theme called `searchform.php` with the following code

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Blog Posts', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
    </label>
<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( ' >', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
</form>
```

and then separately a file called `search.php` with the following:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php //this prints out your search form 
    get_search_form(); ?>
    <h1 class="page-title search-page-title">
        search results for <?php echo get_search_query(); ?>
    </h1>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        No results for "<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just did that. The footer underneath the search box disappeared. But when I enter a search term, the page is loading endlessly and it shows nothing.

Comment: you might wanna check your footer.php code for any inconsistencies

Comment: Thanks. My footer has logo, location info, menu items, subscribe to newsletter box, and social icons. What inconsistencies should I look for? What do you think might be creating this conflict?

Comment: I examined the footer.php file. Not sure where there might be a conflict. I am adding it here below. Can you please take a look and help me find the problem? Thank you so much!